# Extracting all values from nested JSON

Tags: java, json, gson

I am fairly new to JSON parser and I am trying to extract all data set from "sizes" tag i.e extracting values (small, yes, xsmall, NO, Medium and yes) from the JSON file in a complex nested loop but doesn't work.  I am using GSON to parse the JSON file and using JAVA as programming language

Here how the JSON file looks like in general

```
{ response: "ok",
  prodinfo: {
    sizes: [ 
      { size:"small", 
        available: "yes"
      }, 
      { size:"xsmall", 
        available: "No"
      },
      { size:"Medium", 
        available: "yes"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This is what i did

```
int array = jsonParser14.parse(json14).getAsJsonObject().get("ProdInfo").getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonArray("sizes").size();
JsonArray sizes = (JsonArray) jsonParser15.parse(json15).getAsJsonObject().get("ProdInfo").getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonArray("sizes");
for (int i = 0; i <= array; i++) {
    String size = sizes.get(i).getAsString();
    System.out.println("data extracted are: " + size);
}
```

Your help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Have you built classes in which store those data ? If so you don't need a loop. There's many way to do that, show us what you tried.

Comment: hello guys. I have just added GSON parser and loop that i have done. Any idea will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I usually treat this by making a public class with required fields :

```
public class ProdSize {
    public String size;
    public String available;
}

public class ProdInfo {
    public ProdSize[] sizes;
}

public class Message {
    public String response;
    public ProdInfo prodinfo;
}
```

And then I just have to do this in gson :

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
Message mess = gson.fromJson(theJsonString, Message.class);
```

Then, I don't have any loop to do to parse the JSON. I directly have my sizes in

```
mess.prodinfo.sizes
```

For example you can print them like this

```
for (int i=0; i<mess.prodinfo.sizes.length; i++) {
   ProdSize size = mess.prodinfo.sizes[i];
   System.out.println("Size " + size.size + " -> " + size.available);
}
```

Comment: Hello dystroy. thanks for reply but however i cannot extract each field in sizes from your idea. Would it be possible to show me how you do that? Right now when i run below code i get output as "[Lgsonparser$ProdSize;@787171"
  JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
  FileReader json = new FileReader("h:\\test.json");
  JsonElement theJsonString = jsonParser.parse(json);
  Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
  Message mess = gson.fromJson(theJsonString, Message.class);
  System.out.println(mess.prodinfo.sizes);
 }
 
      }

 }

Comment: I completed my answer with a loop to show how you can iterate.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
var sizes = json.prodinfo.sizes;
for (item in sizes) {
    if (sizes.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
        var isAvailable = sizes[item].available;
        alert(isAvailable);
    }

}​
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/nG88B/3/

**Edit**:
Looks like you need to parse the JSON first. In which case (if it's valid) you can do:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
```

Comment: OP is trying to parse in java using gson.